# Wordpress seems to replace all underscores with dashes since 9.1.2 in uploaded files. How can I remove this?

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I have noticed that it seems like that Wordpress is replacing all underscores with dashes in uploaded file names since the lastest update (9.1.2). However, I need the underscores in the file names to be kept.

I found a plugin that I modified but it doesn't seem to help.. See the code below.

```
function mfl_make_filename_lowercase($filename) {
    $info = pathinfo($filename);
    $ext  = empty($info['extension']) ? '' : '.' . $info['extension'];
    $name = basename($filename, $ext);
    $name = preg_replace('/-/', '_', $name);
    return strtolower($name) . $ext;
}
add_filter('sanitize_file_name', 'mfl_make_filename_lowercase', 10);
```

I have looked around quite a bit, I have checked the formatting.php in wp-includes and changed the preg_replace to '_' instead of '-' where I found it. I have done the same in files.php in wp-admin/includes.

I must be missing something. Or is it simply not possible? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Swap out the dashes by underscores using this code:

```
    function image_meta_upon_upload( $post_ID ) {

        if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $post_ID ) ) {

            $my_image_title = get_post( $post_ID )->post_title;
            $my_image_title = preg_replace( '%\s*[-]+\s*%', '_',  $my_image_title );
            $my_image_meta = array(
                'ID' => $post_ID,               // Specify the image (ID) to be updated
                'post_title'    => $my_image_title,     // Set image Title to sanitized title
            );
            wp_update_post( $my_image_meta );
        }
    }
        add_action( 'add_attachment', 'image_meta_upon_upload' );
```

You can insert this code into functions.php, but if you want to preserve it after theme update better solution is to use plugins like code snippets or wpcodebox.

Answer (score 0):

Google treats - as word separator, but not _.
Here is [an article](http://www.ecreativeim.com/blog/2011/03/seo-basics-hyphen-or-underscore-for-seo-urls/) that explains it.

But if you still looking for a solution here is the answer

check out wp-includes/formatting.php

on line 1241 you will get sanitize_title_with_dashes function find

```
$title = strtolower($title);
$title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
$title = str_replace('.', '-', $title);
$title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
$title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
$title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
$title = trim($title, '-');
```

swap out the dashes by underscore

Note that any posts you've created before this change, and rely on the  %postname% permalink structure tag, will be broken.

In that case you'll need to go back and republish those post so the dashes are swapped out for the underscores. Or just write yourself a little SQL to replace them.

Comment: Not good idea to change Wordpress system files, during next update the changes will be replaced. However, the OP can write small filter function and place it in current theme's `functions.php` file, that will override the logic of the `sanitize_title_with_dashes()`.

Comment: Sorry I meant the file names of uploaded files, not titles of pages or posts.. I have updated my question.

Comment: Does anybody have any tips on how to replace dashes in uploaded filenames with underscores? Please?

Comment: you can use http://wordpress.org/plugins/file-renaming-on-upload/ plugin for renaming as well as u can check media file renamer also.

Comment: Sorry for my late comment! I downloaded it but it seems it isn't capable of actually replacing - with _ , it just removes it... What I need is for - to always be replaced with _ on upload.